# Publishing ASP.NET MvC to Azure with SQLite - data fetching fails

Tags: azure, sqlite

Just created a simple ASP.NET MvC project, to list blood pressure measurements. I opted to use SQLite as a database as it is (supposedly) embedded into the project, therefore eliminating the need for an external database. Which is expensive, and the reason why I chose to go with SQLite. That way I would only need to host the web app, which is free, if I chose the free tier, F1.

Publishing through VS2022 is successful, and the app shows correctly, except it shows none of the measurements. Which renders the app ((no) pun intended) useless, at least as a cloud app. I have done some research, and changed the publishingsettings a couple of times, but this is how they look right now.

```
Configuration: Release
Target Framework: net6.0
Deployment Mode: Self-contained
Target Runtime: win-x86
File Publish Options: None of the options chosen

Databases: Default Connection - Use this connection string at runtime:
=> Data source=bloodpressuremeasurements.db
Entity Framework Migrations: BloodPressureContext (name of the DbContext)
- Apply this migration on publish: NOT chosen, since it gave me an exception and publish failed
Site Extension Options: Install ASP.NET Core Logging Integration Site Extension
- NOT chosen
```

I also tried changing the option for the db file to `Copy To Output Directory: Copy always.`
That didn't change a thing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The website works now as intended, with all the data shown. It looks like the problem stems from scaffolding read and write methods, which made **Visual Studio 2022** pull in **EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**. Which is not what I wanted, since I'm using SQLite.

That in turn created some service dependencies under **Connected Services**, one of them being SQL Server something. It also appeared under the **Publish** menu, and seems to have caused the compilator to view the connection string as an SQL Server database connection.

I created a new app, and copied the code from the first one. I was careful not to scaffold, as I only need a **Get** method, to show all measurements. I need none of the other methods in CRUD, neither **Post**, **Delete**, nor **Update**. I will add new measurements by running the app again locally, and read the measurements from a CSV file (did that in the beginning). Then I will publish the app anew, with the updated SQLite database.